# PHP $_GET issue

Tags: php, mysql

I hope you can help me with this issue, I like to do this with PHP for example:

> ?id=5&language=en

Firstly the ?id=5 is a simple page, also language is defined in directories, but I wanna to make this

> ?id=5,en

I don't like to put `&language=en`, only comma and en How can I do this ?

Comment: This could turn out to be a bad idea in the long run, as you won't be able to easily manipulate the query string, mix in new values etc.. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 10):

```
list($id, $lang) = explode(',', $_GET['id']);
```

And then use `$id` and `$lang` how you want.

Comment: Thank you @David Gillen, In this case $id = $_GET['id'] and $lang = $_GET['lang'] it is.

Comment: In the instance where you have `?id=5,en` as your get param instead of `?id=5&language=en`. Then my code will put `5` into `$id` and `en` into `$lang`.